# Merging part of kernel - best way?

Tags: kernel, drivers, git, merge

For example: I have a kernel 3.16 from my embedded support, but I want to have some network wireless drivers from 3.19. What is the best way to merge only this drivers (not full kernel)?

1. I tried merge, but it results in many conflicts.
2. Copying files from 3.19 to 3.16 is a lot of work and results in many missing functions. I have to copy includes also, and these includes needs other includes and new functions, etc. This is a never ending work or never working.
3. I tried to make a `diff` between some commits and try to cherry-pick them, but I'm not sure that `git diff A..B` is really working. Sometimes we have merges between A..B with different branches and it's a real mess to consider "what is what". On the other hand, I have to decide which cherry-pick is important for wireless driver and which isn't.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Is there no way you can use 3.19? It would probably make your life easier instead of cherrypicking

Comment: It's something like that. I have embedded platform and processor producer supports a 3.16 kernel with his modifications for diffrent hardware to work. Unfortunately i need some mainline drivers from 3.19, but mainline kernel don't have changes for this specific chip. For me it's easier to take drivers from 3.19 than do it other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the best option for me was :

1. Copy drivers files from 3.19 into 3.16 directly.
2. Before commit, thanks to git difftool check every change with previous code.

   - If change uses newer kernel function then get back to older function or add newer function files from 3.19 kernel
3. Compile - if errors then get back to 2.
4. Test.
5. Commit changes.